# Lock row "FOR UPDATE OF" specific table using Ecto/Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I would like to acquire a `lock` using `FOR UPDATE OF table_name`. In comparison to `FOR UPDATE`, `FOR UPDATE OF` only locks the row in the specified table and the joined rows are not blocked. However, when I try to do it with Ecto using the following snippet it fails.

```
query =
  Call
  |> join_other_tables() # custom methods
  |> Query.lock("FOR UPDATE OF calls")
```

The reason is Ecto uses an alias for `calls`, for example, `c0`, which means that I also have to use the alias in the lock expression to get it working.

```
query =
  Call
  |> join_other_tables() # custom methods
  |> Query.lock("FOR UPDATE OF c0")
```

Using the alias does not look like a proper way to do it. Is there any other way to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `Ecto v3` there is no way to pass the parameterized value to `Query.lock`. It accepts [binaries only](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.0.7/lib/ecto/query/builder/lock.ex#L18).

[Named bindings] won’t work either because `Ecto` internally [generates aliases as it wants](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/mysql/connection.ex#L617).

---

The following approach would be the nearest one, but it does not work either because `Ecto.Query.lock/2` does not allow interpolation.

Use [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1), that has an interpolation ability, with the keyword query syntax. Somewhat like:

```
from c in Call,
  join: ..., # custom methods
  lock: fragment("FOR UPDATE OF ?", c)
```

Comment: This throws the next error: `fragment("FOR UPDATE OF ?", c) is not a valid lock. For security reasons, a lock must always be a literal string`

Comment: Damn, [indeed](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.0.7/lib/ecto/query/builder/lock.ex#L18) they allow only binaries there. You might try [named binding](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-named-bindings) then. Let me know if it succeeds, I’ll either update the answer or delete it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either. It looks like Ecto uses these aliases internally but for the actual SQL query it [still generates new aliases](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/mysql/connection.ex#L617).

Comment: Yes, and the generator is private. Sorry for saying that, but it sounds like you are to stay with the last resort: `"c0"` hardcoded. I will remove the answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the effort anyway. You can leave the answer, perhaps it could be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Or add an update to the answer that there is currently no way to do it, as of version Ecto version 3.

Answer (score 2):

Note it looks like you can now use a fragment to interpolate the table name in, see https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/pull/189. So the solution from Aleksei should now work:

```
from c in Call,
  join: ..., # custom methods
  lock: fragment("FOR UPDATE OF ?", c)
```